# Starting ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.90 (refs/branch-heads/3770@{#xxxx}) on port xxxxx Only local connections are allowed

Tags: selenium

While running simple selenium test in google chrome, got below error. (Windows 10)

Starting ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.90 (a6dcaf7e3ec6f70a194cc25e8149475c6590@@@@-refs/branch-heads/3770@{#XXXX}) on port XXXXX
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.

Comment: Greetings and welcome. I believe that this post could use some example code to be more understandable. Can you include Selenium code that is raising this error?

Comment: That's normal.  It's just a reminder because ChromeDriver could possibly be hijacked by malicious code.  http://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations